# How to allocate a void* array on the heap?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, allocation

I want to use the windows api call `GetWriteWatch()`. This method takes an `void*` array that I allocated on the stack like that: `void* lpAddresses[PAGE_COUNT];` 
The problem now is, that `PAGE_COUNT` needs to be large and this leads to a stackoverflow.
How do I write this to allocate the memory on the heap?
I tried:

```
void* lpAddresses = ::operator new[](PAGE_COUNT); 
void* lpAddresses = ::operator new(PAGE_COUNT); 
void* lpAddresses = malloc(PAGE_COUNT*sizeof(void*));
```

but that results in an error code from `GetWriteWatch()`

The version on the stack that works:

```
ULONG_PTR lpdwCount = PAGE_COUNT;
void *lpAddresses[PAGE_COUNT];
ULONG lpdwGranularity;
UINT result = GetWriteWatch(WRITE_WATCH_FLAG_RESET, m_rawMemory.as_void, m_alloc_size, lpAddresses, &lpdwCount, &lpdwGranularity);
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you call `GetWriteWatch` after allocating the array on the heap? Why isn't it included into the question?

Comment: `void* lpAddresses[PAGE_COUNT]` is an array of `void*` pointers. The `new[]` equivalent is `void** lpAddresses = new void*[PAGE_COUNT];`, or better `std::vector<void*> lpAddresses(PAGE_COUNT);`

Comment: The result from GetWriteWatch != 0. Yep I passed it with the & then. Still no luck.

Comment: No, no, no! My mistake. If you use the `malloc` version, you will have to pass `(PVOID *) lpAddresses`. Not `&lpAddresses`. Passing `&lpAddresses` is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you could post that as an answer I'll accept this as the answer. Thank you. Both versions work.

Answer (score -1):

When you use this function you have to allocate memory using the windows function `VirtualAlloc()` using the flag `MEM_WRITE_WATCH`

Something like this:

```
lpAddress = VirtualAlloc(NULL, PAGE_COUNT, MEM_WRITE_WATCH, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366573(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why??? `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` is for memory pages to be watched. It has nothing to do with allocation of this array memory at all. That's what your linked page says.

Comment: Thanks but it is not about the monitored memory. I want to heap allocate the array to pass and recieve the page adresses so my stack won't die.

Comment: He already said stack memory works fine. So the solution cannot possibly be that he needs VirtualAlloc right???

Comment: @AnT - perhaps you should *read* the linked page. It says: 'This address must be in a memory region that is allocated by the VirtualAlloc function using MEM_WRITE_WATCH.'

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow: No, it is you who has to read it more carefully. That remark you quoted applies to `lpBaseAddress`, not to `lpAddresses`. Exactly what I said in my comment above. This question is about allocating memory for `lpAddresses`.

Comment: @AnT - ah, my apologies - you are 100% correct. I vaguely remembered a similar issue sometime ago and I read the doco too carelessly.

Answer (score -1):

The memory allocation itself in your `malloc` version is perfectly correct. (The `::operator new` versions are incorrect.) Just keep in mind that in order to pass a pointer initialized as follows

```
void* lpAddresses = malloc(PAGE_COUNT*sizeof(void*));
// Assuming `void *` is synonymous with `PVOID`
```

to `GetWriteWatch` you will have to cast the pointer to the proper type, i.e. you have to pass `(PVOID *) lpAddresses`. Passing `&lpAddresses` instead (which is what you did, according to the comments) is completely and hopelessly incorrect.

If I decided to use `malloc` in this case I would have done it slightly differently

```
PVOID *lpAddresses = (PVOID *) malloc(PAGE_COUNT * sizeof *lpAddresses);
```

i.e. I would perform the cast at the point of memory allocation, and after that passed plain `lpAddresses` to `GetWriteWatch`.

Alternatively you can use

```
PVOID *lpAddresses = new PVOID[PAGE_COUNT];
```

in which case you will pass plain `lpAddresses` to the function.

You can also use `std::vector` or any other memory allocation mechanism. Just keep observing the proper indirection level.